# How to one-hot-encode df column with list separated by pipe

Tags: python, dataframe, one-hot-encoding

I have a df column containing lists separated by pipes and including extraneous information. I'm having trouble one-hot-encoding the list. For example, I want:

| Student | Major History |
| --- | --- |
| 111 | ACCT (198720)|MGMT (200045)|NDGD (200630) |
| 112 | INST (201326)|ACCT (198720) |

to encode as:

| Student | ACCT | MGMT | NDGD | INST |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 112 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 |

I've tried

```
df['Major History'].str.join('|').str.get_dummies()
```

but it seems to one-not-encode by individual characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there - the correct code would be:

`df['Major History'].str.get_dummies('|')`

If you also want to replace the numeric characters, the full code would be:

`df['Major History'].str.replace('\d|\(|\)| ','').str.get_dummies()`